# Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined after upgrade

Tags: jhipster

I just upgraded an existing project to the latest version of jhipster. When logging in I get a Javascript error message: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined. I can see that in the login.controller.js a new line is added event.preventDefault(); (the problem is caused by this line) is added, which wasn't there in the previous version. I don't know where to look for a solution (my Angular knowledge is very limited). Can anyone give me a hint of where to look? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in `login.controller.js`, it's in `account/login/login.html`. Maybe you have customized this view template and did not update it. It should include this form definition:

```
<form class="form" role="form" ng-submit="login($event)">
```

Comment: That definitelty solved my problem. Thanks! Sorry to have bothered you guys with this. I should've figured this one out myself. Thanks for you help!